# neo4j 3.5.x GC running over and over again, even after just starting the server

Tags: neo4j, garbage-collection

Our application uses neo4j 3.5.x (tried both community and enterprise editions) to store some data.

No matter how we setup memory in conf/neo4j.conf (tried with lots of combinations for initial/max heap settings from 4 to 16 GB), the GC process runs periodically every 3 seconds, putting the machine to its knees, slowing the whole system down.

There's a combination (8g/16g) that seems to make stuff more stable, but a few minutes (20-30) after our system is being used, GC kicks again on neo4j and goes into this "deadly" loop.

If we restart the neo4j server w/o restarting our system, as soon as our system starts querying neo4j, GC starts again... (we've noticed this behavior consistently).

We've had a 3.5.x community instance which was working fine from last week (when we've tried to switch to enterprise). We've copied over the data/ folder from enterprise to community instance and started the community instance... only to have it behave the same way the enterprise instance did, running GC every 3 seconds.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

[Screenshot of jvisualvm with 8g/16g of heap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GTqx.png)

On debug.log, only these are significative:

2019-03-21 13:44:28.475+0000 WARN [o.n.b.r.BoltConnectionReadLimiter] Channel [/127.0.0.1:50376]: client produced 301 messages on the worker queue, auto-read is being disabled.
2019-03-21 13:45:15.136+0000 WARN [o.n.b.r.BoltConnectionReadLimiter] Channel [/127.0.0.1:50376]: consumed messages on the worker queue below 100, auto-read is being enabled.
2019-03-21 13:45:15.140+0000 WARN [o.n.b.r.BoltConnectionReadLimiter] Channel [/127.0.0.1:50376]: client produced 301 messages on the worker queue, auto-read is being disabled.

And I have a neo4j.log excerpt from around the time the jvisualvm screenshot shows but it's 3500 lines long... so here it is on Pastebin:

[neo4j.log excerpt from around the time time the jvisualvm screenshot was taken](https://pastebin.com/YjybhGBN)

```
JUST_PUT_THIS_TO_KEEP_THE_SO_EDITOR_HAPPY_IGNORE...
```

Hope this helps, I have also the logs for the Enterprise edition if needed, though they are a bit more 'cahotic' (neo4j restarts in between) and I have no jvisualvm screenshot for them

Comment: To have some GC is not a problem, but to have some blocking GC that freeze your server is.  You  should share more information (your configuration, a screenshot of the jvisualvm, an extract of the debug.log, ...) if you want us to help you.

Comment: I've just edited the article adding a jvisualvm screenshot and excerpt of logs, hope this helps. TIA.

Comment: You may want to run the consistency checker on an offline version of your store, just in case

Comment: ineo@fuentes:~/.ineo/instances/neo4j-ent-live-p20000$ ./bin/neo4j-admin check-consistency --database=graph.db
2019-03-22 00:38:56.540+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.s.f.RecordFormatSelector] Selected RecordFormat:StandardV3_4[v0.A.9] record format from store /home/ineo/.ineo/instances/neo4j-ent-live-p20000/data/databases/graph.db
2019-03-22 00:38:56.544+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.s.f.RecordFormatSelector] Format not configured. Selected format from the store: RecordFormat:StandardV3_4[v0.A.9]
....................  90%
................Checking node and relationship counts
....
.................... 100%

Comment: All looks fine from the consistency check ran above, and it looks like there's no report file output, so all went fine, the DB should be consistent.

Comment: BTW, the neo4j java driver our system is using is the latest (at least latest from beginning of March), 1.7.2